# Getting errors and not sure why still learning COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am looking to nest two loops together. I want to find the largest integer that is divisible from 1 to 20 evenly. My code for the program is as follows:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. EULER3.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 startNum PIC 9(10) VALUE 380.
    01 counter PIC 9(2).
    01 check PIC 9(1) VALUE 0.
    01 finalVal PIC 9(10)
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-PROCEDURE. 

PERFORM whileLoop UNTIL check = 1.
DISPLAY "Largest number divisible by 19 thru 20 " startNum. 
STOP RUN.

whileLoop.
    SET counter TO 11.
    DISPLAY counter.
    PERFORM forLoop UNTIL counter = 20

forLoop.
    IF FUNCTION MOD(startNum, counter) = 0
        IF counter = 19
            SET finalVal TO startNum.
            ADD 1 TO check.
    ELSE
        ADD 20 TO startNum

    ADD 1 TO counter.
    END-IF.
```

And the Console is:

```
 jdoodle.cobc:30: warning: line not terminated by a newline
 jdoodle.cobc:9: error: syntax error, unexpected PROCEDURE, expecting EXTERNAL or EXTERNAL-FORM or GLOBAL or IDENTIFIED
 jdoodle.cobc:10: error: PROCEDURE DIVISION header missing
 jdoodle.cobc:10: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier
 jdoodle.cobc: in paragraph 'whileLoop':
 jdoodle.cobc:21: error: 'forLoop' is not defined
 jdoodle.cobc:19: error: invalid expression
 jdoodle.cobc:26: error: syntax error, unexpected ELSE
 jdoodle.cobc:30: error: syntax error, unexpected END-IF
 jdoodle.cobc:19: error: 'forLoop' is not defined
```

I am not sure why it is saying I don't have a procedure division. I have written my program in Python and used this method, hence why I have named my areas forLoop and whileLoop.

Answer (score 2):

I may have missed some other syntax errors.

```
01 finalVal PIC 9(10)  add a final period.  

SET finalVal TO startNum.   remove the period.

ADD 1 TO check.   remove the period.

ADD 20 TO startNum   add an END-IF

ADD 1 TO counter.   remove the period.
```

Comment: Thank you! I began editing and looking over my program and kicking myself for posting without thinking too much.

Comment: Also try to restrict use of SET... TO... to 88-level values and use MOVE... TO..., as SET is not allowed on general variable in every Cobol dialect ; and MOVE follows the Cobol convention having source (r-values) args preceding destination ones.

Comment: The whileLoop also needs a final dot